# Table preview in newer HUE

Tags: impala, hue

In HUE version 3.7.0, in the query editor (for say, Impala), you could pull up a preview of a table by clicking the[image] button to the right of a table name. In HUE 3.9.0, this button dissapeared from the query editor, but seems to be present in the Metastore Manager. Is there a way to enable it in the query editor?

Answer (score 0):

The preview button was split in two http://demo.gethue.com/beeswax/#query, then both were merged together. So it should still show up in your Hue if you use upstream or CDH.

Comment: So this is weird. I double checked, I'm running 3.9.0. However I don't actually see the preview button, I just see the graph (table analysis) button. Is there maybe an option I need to enable? I do see what you described in the metastore